# «Год Кролика»: как писать?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как правильно?

> Сейчас год Кролика, а черезнедельный год будет годом Дракона.

> Сейчас год кролика, а черезнедельный год будет годом дракона.

Comment: Черезнедельный?  А разве есть такое слово?

Comment: This is my invention.

Comment: Может,  тогда курсивом написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Астрономические названия](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=85#pp85) (ПАС)
**§ 178.** В названиях небесных тел, созвездий и галактик с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме родовых наименований (*звезда, комета, созвездие, планета, астероид* и т. п.) и буквенных обозначений светил (*альфа, бета, гамма* и т. п.), напр.: <...>
***Дева, Водолей, Стрелец*** (созвездия и знаки зодиака)...

> — Теперь скажи мне, что такое год?
> — Колесница мира.
> — Кто везет ее?
> — Ночь и день, холод и жар.
> — Кто ее возницы?
> — Солнце и луна.
> — Сколько они имеют домов?
> — Двенадцать.
> — Кто живет в них?
> Анна сжала руки, чтобы напрячь память, и, закрыв глаза, ответила:
> — Овен, Телец, Близнецы, Рак, Лев, Дева, Весы, Скорпион, Стрелец…
> Анна запнулась, и Готье подсказал:
> — Козерог…
> Анна закончила перечень:
> — Водолей, Рыбы…
> (А. Ладинский. Анна Ярославна)

Думаю, что нет разницы: пишем мы знаки зодиака (по месяцам — двенадцать) или *название* года по восточному календарю (их тоже двенадцать).

Дракон на пороге (поэтому, наверно, у нас в Эстонии оттепель и дождь):

*И вообще ему здорово досталось в этом году. Волей-неволей поверишь в **год Дракона**...* (Еремей Парнов. Третий глаз Шивы);
*Наступил Новый год — **год Дракона**. Говорят, что это доброе существо несет всем счастье и благоденствие* (Д. М. Шварц. Дневник).

P. S. Особенное слово я бы написала так: "чрезнедельный" (по аналогии со словом "чрезмерный").

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр В преддверии Нового года — как не поощрить ваш вопрос?! С Наступающим!

Comment: Знаков зодиака, вообще-то, 13.

Comment: Ну... Это при условии, что Вы Змееносца считаете. Не все школы эзотерики его признают. Надо ведь классификацию переделывать. Для этого нужно время. И консенсус. Пока получается, что астрономы отдельно (Скорпион — Солнце в нем всего 7 дней), астрологи — отдельно.

Comment: Ладно, спорить не буду, не разбираюсь. Дал свой ответ, потому что хотел упомянуть ответ Грамоты. Я знал ответ до того, как его задал Лео. А до этого я после вопроса искал информацию. Это потому, что мне нравилось набирать репутацию. А сейчас дал ответ, потому что знал и хотел рассказать. Это так, чтобы знали.

Comment: Теперь знаю. Достойный ответ. Поддержу. Вот только ссылка (цитата) оформлена неверно. Всех-всех благ!

Comment: А как лучше оформить? В самой цитате "зассылкофицировать" выделенные слова? Спасибо, и вам! С наступающим!

Answer (score 3):

**Дополнительная информация** (о кроликах и зайцах)

Интересно, что в "Русском орфографическом словаре" на сайте "Грамота.ru" (и в других словарях тоже) в статье **о кролике** нет упоминания о том, что есть такой восточный *год Кролика.*

Зато на этом же ресурсе, в "Большом универсальном словаре русского языка", имеется информация [о календарях](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E&mode=slovari):

**Восточный календарь** — основанная на шестидесятилетнем цикле система летосчисления (она распространена в Китае, Японии, Корее и некоторых других странах), включающая в себя пять двенадцатилетних кругов, в которых символом каждого года выступает определённое животное: Бык, Тигр, Коза (Овца), Змея, Обезьяна, Крыса, Лошадь, Кабан (Свинья), Дракон, **Кот (Кошка, Заяц, Кролик)**, Петух, Собака.

Каждое из названий этих животных пишется с прописной буквы — то есть это имена собственные.
И нам уже не столь важно, **кто** и **как** называет уходящий год, важно, что пишется слово "год" со строчной буквы (не праздник ведь длиною в год), а животинка — с прописной:
год Кота (Кошки), год Кролика, год Зайца.

Кстати, в тех же словарях ни о Коте, ни о Кошке тоже нет ни слова, только о Зайце:
[**заяц**](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%86%22&mode=all)...  но: **год Зайца** (*по восточному календарю*), Заяц, Зайца (*о том, кто родился в этот год; созвездие*).

[Немного о животных из гороскопа](https://podarok-ng.ru/Novosti/2023-god-krolikakota-pochemu-zhe-etot-god-dvojnoj-7.html)

Comment: Я правильно понял: год Кролика иначе год Кошки,Зайца?

Comment: С Новым годом, Серж! Ушедший 2023 — это год Кролика или год Кота (где кролик, там и заяц — очень ведь *похожи*, их иногда даже путают; кот и кошка — это вообще *одно* животное, только самец и самка). 1. https://www.kp.ru/woman/goroskop/chernyj-vodyanoj-krolik/ ("Комсомольская правда"). 2. https://www.gastronom.ru/text/2023-god-kota-i-krolika-kak-v-jetom-razobratsja-1016643. 3. https://vn.ru/news-kakoy-simvol-2023-goda-po-vostochnomu-kalendaryu-chernyy-kot-ili-vodyanoy-krolik/.

Comment: И вас, @Римма Михайлова. Жаль, что здесь всех одним разом поздравить невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто Кролик более распространенное название, видимо.

Comment: @Серж Поздравляю всех одним разом!!!

Comment: Спасибо, и вас!

Answer (score 2):

Недавний [ответ Грамоты](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0&mode=spravka) (не на мой вопрос; в нем нет прямого упоминания, можете пропустить), хочу представить (постоянно слежу за справочным бюро):

> Здравствуйте, подскажите какие строчные/прописные первые буквы в словосочетании "год дракона" в середине предложения (публицистический стиль): год дракона, Год дракона, год Дракона, Год Дракона?
> ОТВЕТ
> Ответ на Ваш вопрос содержится в академическом «Русском орфографическом словаре» под ред. В. В. Лопатина и О. Е. Ивановой (М., 2023), размещенном на нашем портале. В этом словаре закреплены в нормативном написании не только отдельные слова, но и различные неоднословные единицы — устойчивые обороты, имена, названия. Конечно, орфографический словарь не является словарем собственных имен и не может вместить в себя все имена и названия, но он стремится охватить самые разнообразные модели, которые даются через достаточно известные примеры. По таким примерам можно определить, как пишется другое название такой же структуры.
>
> Как найти неоднословную единицу в словаре? Она может даваться в заголовке словарной статьи, а может включаться в текст статьи, заголовком которой является ключевое слово искомого выражения. К первому типу относятся, например, Новый год и старый Новый год, а ко второму — название **года по восточному календарю**, о котором был задан вопрос (посмотрите также статьи мышь, змея, кролик и под.).
>
> Чтобы найти в словаре сочетание слов — заголовок словарной статьи, его нужно набрать в поисковой строке в кавычках (см., например, високосный год).

Слова, которые я выделил в ответе, — это [ссылка](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%22&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71) на орфографический словарь. Её дала Грамота в ответе на вопрос. Если по ней перейти, мы увидим это:

> драк**о**н, -а; но: **год Дракона** (*по восточному календарю*), Драк**о**н, -а (*о том, кто родился в этот год; созвездие*).

Я выделил то, что вам нужно. В итоге будет правильно так:

*Сейчас **год Кролика**, а черезнедельный год будет **годом Дракона***.

Comment: https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=Упоминание&mode=all

Comment: @Слава Я же хотел написать с И... Ладно, спасибо, сейчас исправлю. С наступающим!

Comment: Я подправила. Мне *кажется*, что так лучше, аккуратнее. Всё ли, Максим, соответствует вашим задумкам?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, спасибо, так лучше.

Answer (score 2):

```
По восточному календарю 2024-й — год Зеленого 
Деревянного Дракона. В китайской культуре мифическое 
животное символизирует власть, благородство, честь, 
удачу и успех.
```

**ПОЗДРАВЛЯЮ ВСЕХ УЧАСТНИКОВ ФОРУМА С ГОДОМ  ЗЕЛЕНОГО ДЕРЕВЯННОГО ДРАКОНА!**

Попробую в последний день уходящего года взглянуть на вопрос с **нестандартной** точки зрения.

1. **Три ответа на вопрос** — вероятно, он вызвал повышенный интерес у участников.  Но вот в чем здесь **проблема**, был ли у нас **выбор** при написании?

**Примечание.** Это то, о чем надо думать **ВСЕГДА**,  определяя ценность и качество вопроса. **ЕСТЬ ЛИ ВЫБОР И В ЧЕМ ОН СОСТОИТ?** Вопросы без проблемы — это тоже проблема для сайта. Другой вариант: отвечающий должен увидеть эту проблему и обозначить ее. И это уж качество **ответа.**

2. Посмотрим на варианты, записанные как нарицательные сочетания: ***год кролика, год дракона.***   Имеют ли  они **смысл**? Можно ли год связывать с реальным или воображаемым **животным**, указанным в **словаре?**
3. Думаю, что ответ очевиден — конечно же нет! Это же, к примеру, не **год защиты** кроликов или драконов. **Структура этого названия такова:** приложение или  родовое название ***(год***) + имя собственное по восточному календарю (***Дракона, Кролика)***.
4. **ИСТОЧНИКИ**

Это решение можно проверить **по словарю РАН**: **дракон**, -а; но: **год Дракона** (по восточному календарю), Дракон, -а (о том, кто родился в этот год; созвездие).

Но вот **года Кролика** там нет. Тогда смотрим ответы Справочной службы. [https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=год%20змеи&mode=spravka](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B8&mode=spravka)

**№ 267747**
Как правильно оформлять на письме (интересуют кавычки и прописные/строчные) в названиях годов **по китайскому календарю?** Вариаций превеликое множество: **Год змеи,** Год Змеи, год Змеи... И как быть в случае наращивания определений: г(Г)од черной водяной з(З)меи.

**ОТВЕТ**
Правильно: **год Змеи, год Собаки, год Крысы и т. д.** Такая фиксация – в академическом «Русском орфографическом словаре» **под ред. В. В. Лопатина и О. Е. Ивановой (4-е изд., М., 2012)**. Корректно также: год Черной Водяной Змеи.

5. В вопросе **выбор** был обозначен, но в ответах он **не обсуждается**. Указываются различные **источники,** где можно найти информацию, но о самом решении не говорится. А если представить, что источников нет, тогда **мы можем решить задачу** по общему принципу в этой теме (выбор прописных и строчных букв). **Вот что по-настоящему интересно.**

И дополнительный вопрос: если в названии есть **определения**, то как их писать?  Ответ такой: это условные (не реальные, **символические**) названия,  они входят в имя собственное и пишутся с прописной буквы. Эту информацию я предлагаю автору вопроса в качестве бонуса.

Вот такие у меня пожелания к **КАЧЕСТВУ** ответов в новом году.

**ДРАКОН,** -а; м. [греч. drákōn]. 1. В славянской мифологии: **Сказочное чудовище, пожирающее людей и животных**, в виде крылатого огнедышащего змея с когтями льва, крыльями, похожими на крылья летучей мыши, раздвоенными языком и хвостом. В искусстве часто изображается архангел Михаил с драконом у ног, а также святой Георгий, пронзающий дракона копьем, что символизирует победу добра над злом; дракон на цепи означает побежденное зло. 2. **Древесная ящерица,** обладающая способностью к полёту (обитает в тропических странах). **3. О жестоком, безжалостном человеке.** Командир - настоящий д. Морской дракон. Небольшая колючепёрая рыба (обитает в южных морях).

**КРОЛИК**, -а; м. Небольшой родственный зайцу зверёк из отряда грызунов. // Мех этого животного. Дикий к. Воротник из кролика. Шубка из кролика.

Comment: «Вот такие у меня пожелания **к КАЧЕСТВУ ответов**». Скажите, Sharon, а зачем *автору* вопроса *эти* рекомендации? Он ведь не отвечает, а спрашивает. «И дополнительный вопрос: если в названии есть **определения**, то они как пишутся? Почему они так пишутся?» Вы у кого, собственно, спрашиваете? Простите, но бо́льшая часть Вашего ответа является чем угодно, но только не ответом. Зачем в вашем тексте так много требований к *другим* отвечающим и так много ненужной информации? Вы всегда призывали отвечать коротко и конкретно. А сами, мне кажется, "растеклись".

Comment: И Вас с праздником наступающим, *Sharon*! Из Ваших рассуждений я тоже ничего нового не почерпнула. Если уж Вы пользуетесь ответами, представленными на "Грамоте" (хотя сами часто говорили: неизвестно, кто там отвечает) и словарями, имеющимися на этом сайте, то можно было заглянуть и в *Большой универсальный словарь русского языка*.

Comment: **Восточный календарь** – основанная на шестидесятилетнем цикле система летосчисления (она распространена в Китае, Японии, Корее и нек. др. странах), включающая в себя пять двенадцатилетних кругов, в к-рых символом каждого года выступает определённое животное: Бык, Тигр, Коза (Овца), Змея, Обезьяна, Крыса, Лошадь, Кабан (Свинья), Дракон, **Кот (Кошка, Заяц, Кролик)**, Петух, Собака. (https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E&mode=slovari) Ну не может же словарь РАН объять всё и вся (тем более — такой тонкий, многогранный, многотысячелетний Восток).

Comment: С наступающим)!

Comment: Спасибо!  Немного осталось, летят минутки, Дракончик уже рядом. Что же у него попросить: благородство, честь, удачу или  успех?

Answer (score 1):

По астрологической традиции, названия знаков восточного гороскопа и Зодиака пишутся с прописной (Большой) буквы. Обращу внимание на переизбыток в вашем предложении слова "год". У вас 9 слов, и 3 из них одинаковые. В русском языке около 200 тыс. слов, а можно накопать и до полумиллиона. Насочинять можно — миллионы. И только плохие авторы, типа раздутых до святых классиков и писак дешёвых детективов, не способны написать и одного абзаца без "стоял", "был", "мог", "сказал", "который". Обогащайте речь, вносите в неё разнообразие, если вы желаете создавать качественные тексты.

Comment: А зачем в информационном тексте так много эмоций и экспрессии? Это нарушение стиля.

Comment: @Sharon вы путаете экспрессию с полезной для автора информацией. Если я захочу увидеть на этом форуме экспрессию, я очередной раз напишу критический комментарий под вашим постом, после чего очередной раз от вас последует около трёх сообщений с возмущениями о том, как я осмелился усомниться в вашей правоте. А затем вы, как всегда, сольётесь, сказав, что не хотите продолжать диалог. Вот это я привожу в качестве иллюстрации "экспрессии". А в случае моего поста нет ни обид, ни возмущений, а вполне себе справедливые размышления о богатстве языка.

Comment: А вот не надо людей оскорблять! Особенно без повода. Рассуждаете о богатстве языка, а в каждом слове злость и агрессия. И все, я уже сливаюсь) Дальше можете разговаривать с пустым пространством или сами с собой. А то это опасно для здоровья.

Comment: Предсказуемо. Оставим без ответа вопрос о том, чем именно и где конкретно "оскорблённые мною люди".

Comment: Да, представьте. После общения с вами хочется прогуляться по зимнему лесу. Отчего так?  Подумайте на досуге, насколько людям приятно общаться с вами. С наступающим новым годом!

Comment: @Sharon  мне всё равно, что вам хочется. Общайтесь по теме форума. Жалобы на меня можете излагать где-то в личном блоге или где вам заблагорассудится. А тут не флудите, не мешайте людям отвечать.